# com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.RestClientException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["self"] not found

Tags: java, spring, jira, rest-client

I'm getting following error -

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.RestClientException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["self"] not found.

[ERROR] 2020-12-03 17:31:58.387 [scheduling-1] TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.RestClientException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["self"] not found.
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:45) ~[jira-rest-java-client-core-5.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.vmware.vulnerability.vulnerabilityanalyzer.util.JiraUtil.createIssue(JiraUtil.java:53) ~[classes/:?]
```

I searched a lot about this error and found that it could be version issue, so I changed to 5.2.0 in dependecies

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
        <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried all combinations above by removing fugue or by adding it, but still I'm facing same issue.